# Computing PDF of Products of Two Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I've been stuck on this problem for some days. I'm hoping someone would help by chipping in a few comments. I have two i.i.d. r.v.:

$$
f_X(x)=\frac{\left(1-e^{-\frac{x}{\alpha }}\right)^{\tilde{r}-1} exp({-\frac{x \left(K-\tilde{r}+1\right)}{\alpha })}}{\alpha }
$$
and 
$$
f_Y(y)=\frac{\left(1-e^{-\frac{y}{\beta }}\right)^{r-1} exp({-\frac{y (K-r+1)}{\beta })}}{\beta }
$$
Since they are i.i.d, the joint pdf is given as:
$$
f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{\left(1-e^{-\frac{y}{\beta }}\right)^{r-1} \left(1-e^{-\frac{x}{\alpha }}\right)^{\tilde{r}-1} e^{-\frac{x \left(K-\tilde{r}+1\right)}{\alpha }-\frac{y (K-r+1)}{\beta }}}{\alpha  \beta }
$$

Goal is to find the the PDF of Z = XY. Suppose z>0, I'm using the product relation given in Henry Stark's, (page 137, also here on wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution)

$$
f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{1}{\left| y\right| } f_{XY}\left(\frac{z}{y}, y\right) \, dy
$$
Subtituting, I have,

$$
f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{\left(1-e^{-\frac{y}{\beta }}\right)^{r-1} \left(1-e^{-\frac{z}{\alpha  y}}\right)^{\tilde{r}-1} \exp \left(-\frac{z \left(K-\tilde{r}+1\right)}{\alpha  y}-\frac{y (K-r+1)}{\beta }\right)}{\alpha  \beta  y} \, dy
$$

From here, I don't seem to know how to proceed to obtain a closed form equation. Almost at my wits end but hoping I might get some guidance here.

Comment: Neither $f_X$ nor $f_Y$ is a PDF in general.

Comment: Thanks Did. Yes they are. I removed the constants to reduce the form.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in comments, neither $f_X$ nor $f_Y$ is a PDF in general. For example, using the change of variable $t=\mathrm e^{-x/\alpha}$ in $f_X$ yields $\mathrm dt=-t\mathrm dx/\alpha$, hence
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}f_X(x)\mathrm dx=\int_0^1(1-t)^{\tilde{r}-1} t^{K-\tilde{r}}\mathrm dt=\mathrm{Beta}(K-\tilde{r}+1,\tilde{r}).
$$
For each $\bar r\gt0$, there is exactly one value of $K$ such that $f_X$ is a PDF (for example, if $\bar r=2$ then $K=\frac12(1+\sqrt5)$).